# NativeScript build failed. Error - actual and formal argument lists differ in length

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript

Recently I've updated my NativeScript CLI to 2.1.0 & installed Telerik UI plugin. After that. my app build getting fail with the error  "**actual and formal argument lists differ in length**".

Screenshot -

[image]

package.json

```
{
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.bhramaan",
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "2.1.1"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.1",
    "nativescript-angular": "0.1.1",
    "nativescript-plugin-firebase": "^3.0.1",
    "tns-core-modules": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-traverse": "6.9.0",
    "babel-types": "6.9.0",
    "babylon": "6.8.0",
    "filewalker": "0.1.2",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.2",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10"
  }
}
```

I've also removed platform & added once again. But, still now no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is your problem:

```
"tns-android": {
  "version": "2.1.1"
}
"tns-core-modules": "^2.0.0"
```

You **must** have TNS/NativeScript-CLI, TNS-Common-Core and the TNS-Platforms the same version.

Type: **tns info** to easily see what versions you are.

---

Here are the upgrade steps:

To upgrade NativeScript command line

```
npm install -g nativescript@latest
```

To Upgrade the NativeScript Common Core library

```
npm install tns-core-modules@latest --save
```

To Upgrade the platform (replace android with ios for iOS)

```
tns platform remove android
tns platform add android
```

Comment: It's fixed. Thanks for the solution.